# How can I configure read-only LDAP user store so that I can to do identity management?

Tags: wso2

I have a read-only LDAP user store and need to do identity management operation (e.g. account locking). What is the most appropriate way to store my identity claims related to these operations?
Is useful to be implementing a custom listener (UserOperationEventListener) to handle identity claims and store them in a custom place?

Comment: By default all identity related information (except shared roles) are stored in the backend user store (LDAP in your case). Having a custom listener imho you could catch information you need (e. g. login attempts), but unable to map the information back to user claims directly. For LDAP userstore I'd recomment to manage the information in LDAP (e. g. setting policies).  Some time ago I'd recommend to wring your own userstore manager, but it became more difficult since certain carbon version

Answer (score 2):

This is known problem with Read Only user stores. From `<IS_HOME>`/repository/conf/security/identity-mgt.properties you can switch **UserStoreBasedIdentityDataStore**
 to **JDBCIdentityDataStore**.

Identity.Mgt.User.Data.Store=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.store.UserStoreBasedIdentityDataStore

To

Identity.Mgt.User.Data.Store=org.wso2.carbon.identity.mgt.store.JDBCIdentityDataStore

where all identity management claims will be stored in **IDN_IDENTITY_USER_DATA** table [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS570/Identity+Related+Tables